# How to automatically execute some code every time my JSP Application is deployed

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, ant, glassfish

I have a JSP Project, running on Tomcat locally and on Glassfish on the web.

I have to automatically execute a batch (setup timers) as soon as the application is deployed before responding to any request.

Is there a standard way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@WebListener
public class SomeClass implements ServletContextListener{
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //Put code here
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those that don't know, the annotation in the above example tells the servlet container that this is a listener

```
@WebListener
```

If you are configuring using web.xml, you would leave the annotation off of the class and define the listener after filter-mapping, but before servlet in the web.xml file.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>yourpackage.SomeClass</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Either way, the container will run it at startup.

Comment: Ordering is not important anymore since Servlet 2.4 (2003).